# The system cannot find the file specified "\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk"

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I just import project from eclipse to studio, it build successfully but when i am trying to run it on Mobile it shows me error of

```
   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'. >  
 com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run   command:  E:\Android\SDK\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat --dex --output 
 E:\SPBranchOffline\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-  18.0.0-95e‌​90accb2727aa2e3ca98559a315ffbf588d787.jar 
E:\Android\SDK\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\18.0.0‌\support-v4-18.0.0.jar Error Code: 1
```

```js
Waiting for device.
Target device: alps-micromax_a110
Uploading file
 local path: E:\SPBranchOffline\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
 remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.spbranchoffline
I/O Error: E:\MyProjectName\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I don't understand i not even run it so how it creates .apk over there?
How i get rid of that error.
I do search i found that i do not have any code in app.iml file, having 
syntax like **option name="APK_PATH" value="/build/outputs/.."**
If anyone know how i get rid of that error please help me out.

Comment: check your gradle console logs for error and post here

Comment: @RamBabuPudari yes i got something here..


**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  

* What went wrong:  
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.  
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:  
 E:\Android\SDK\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat --dex --output E:\SPBranchOffline\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-18.0.0-95e90accb2727aa2e3ca98559a315ffbf588d787.jar E:\Android\SDK\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\18.0.0\support-v4-18.0.0.jar  
Error Code:
 1**

But i don't understand what is it? please help me

Comment: please post exact error. we can help you

Comment: @RamBabuPudari that's what all i got inside Gradle Console.

Comment: check your jar files if any jar added multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Clean and rebuild project. Also, you should update your build tools, support library, etc from the SDK Manager.

Comment: my problem was my android studio was unable to find class.dex file and unable to create MD5 file becoz of it, I searched stackoverflow for many days but didn't find any solution. But your suggestion to update build tools fixed the issue. Thanks a lot.